# DRF request handler is throwing exception: retrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a model instance in Django Rest Framework 3.6.3 at `/path/to/API/widget/1/`, 1 being the primary key of the widget. It's giving me:

> retrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

From the trace I think I'm doing something to cause `dispatch` to throw an exception when instantiating the handler (from views.py, [source here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/4e08abb6059dbfb7dcdb42a38cd96fa0134798ed/rest_framework/views.py#L486)). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong through when I examine the source. Here's the trace:

Traceback:

```
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  86.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /path/to/API/widget/1/
Exception Value: retrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Here's the view from the `ViewSet`:

```
def retrieve(self, request, some_lookup_field=None):
    instance = self.get_object(pk) # handle multi-tenant access control
    if not instance:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance) # from the class's `serializer_cass` attribute
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you provide your view?

Comment: I just realised I was working completely on the wrong code block - the `retrieve()` view of another `ViewSet` (that doesn't take a `pk` kwarg). If you write that `some_lookup_field != pk` I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your stacktrace, the error is:

> `retrieve()` got an unexpected keyword argument `'pk'`.

Look closely in your `retrieve()` function:

```
def retrieve(self, request, some_lookup_field=None):
    # ____________________________^
    instance = self.get_object(pk) # handle multi-tenant access control
    # _________________________^
    ...
```

You are taking `some_lookup_field` as a parameter and not `pk`, that you use below in `self.get_object(pk)`. Try to rename `some_lookup_field` to `pk`.

Answer (score 1):

This error might because you put wrong urls in your url.py. I've had the same problem in my project